# trouble with java and Linux Manjaro

Tags: manjaro

I am trying to update my operating system. Every time I get error messages because dependencies are violated. This always refers to jre or jdk. I therefore wanted to tackle the problem (without updates is stupid ... ). Basically I wanted to display the installed Java version and get the following message already in the console.

java --version
Unrecognized option: --version
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

How should I continue? I have no idea where to start.

Thanks a lot.